# How can I join and also exclude on two fields in Access?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I need some guidance about making two different but related queries in Access:

1. Query 1: Table 1 joins on matches in Table 2 using two fields and using OR (i.e. can match on one field or the other).
2. Query 2: Table 1 joins on non-matches (excludes) in Table 2 using two fields and using OR (i.e. can match on one field or the other)

Comment: I think you may need to split this question up, since those have different answers. Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by #2; does it match any record in which *either* field A doesn't match in T2 *or* field B doesn't match in T2?

Comment: @NathanTuggy your description of what I want from query # 2 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1: note the parenthesis (you could also do this in join but my preference is in the where statement)  This is approximate code, the syntax may be slightly off for Access SQL but it should help point you in the right direction.

```
WHERE ((table1.fieldA = table2.fieldB 
  AND table1.fieldA = table2.fieldC) OR
  table1.fieldA = table2.fieldD)
```

2:

```
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON (table1.fieldA = table2.fieldB
AND table1.fieldA = table2.fieldC)
OR table1.fieldA = table2.fieldD

WHERE (IS NULL table2.fieldB AND
  IS NULL table2.fieldC) 
  OR IS NULL table2.fieldD
```